# ftp upload tool which sends an email

Tags: email, file-upload, ftp, ftp-client

I'm looking at incorporating an simple ftp upload tool on the site that will enable clients to select the branch they want to send it to who is turn would get an email to notify them of the upload and instructions.

Do you have any suggestions?